# Code doesn't compile in unit tests target (XCode)

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ios4, protocol-buffers

I have a problem with my unit tests in XCode. I have an active target which directly depends on a UnitTests target. I have generated some code with ProtocolBuffers library and I have added these classes together with ProtocolBuffers project to my project. Everything compiles well in the active target, however in the UnitTests target I'm getting the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CRequestMessage", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in CConnection.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I had noticed that the generated m file is not added to the UnitTests target so I added this file to the target. Now I'm getting over a thousand errors, including:

> (...) ../ProtoBuff/Classes/CodedInputStream.h:27: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'PBCodedInputStream'

NSObject is not visible?

Of course before adding the generated code everything had worked and compiled well.

Any ideas how to deal with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add "ProtocolBuffers.h" to your target?